# ControlTemplate not showing Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I'm trying to create a `Button` that contains a grid, with rows that contain certain text.

The `Button` will have two rows, both with different pieces of text.  The text that is passed to the `ControlTemplate` is showing, but not the text specified in the template.

Also, the heights of the Grid rows is not showing.  I want it to expand the height of the button.  In fact, I'm not sure that the Grid is showing at all really.

```
<Window x:Class="MAQButtonTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="695" Width="996">        
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Control" x:Key="1">
            <Grid Width="444">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="51" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="36" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="#286c97">
                    <TextBlock>This is the first piece of text</TextBlock>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="#5898c0">
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="#e9f1f6"></Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="#d2e3ed">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Medium" Margin="52,58,0,0" Foreground="#0c3d5d">Your Quizzes <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Medium" Foreground="#0c3d5d">(7)</TextBlock></TextBlock>
                <Grid>
                    <Button Width="444" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
                        <TextBlock>This is a second piece of text</TextBlock>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here's how it shows at the moment with a rough illustration of what I'm trying to achieve as a button layout:

[image: Current vs What I want]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting the Style of the Button, when you should be setting the Template

Resource:

```
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="ButtonTemplate">
        <Grid Width="444">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="51" />
                <RowDefinition Height="36" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="#286c97">
                <TextBlock>This is the first piece of text</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="#5898c0">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

And the button:

```
    <Button Template="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}" >
        Text 2
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using TargetType as "Control", use Button. You will need to define a button. Use Blend to edit button template to strip all unnecessary content from it.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't realise that I had that still in there.  I have changed it to button and it is still showing in exactly the same way :/